# Magento Show Attributes on list/grid view based on Attribute Set

Tags: magento, attributes

I have followed the guide here to allow layout updates to be applied based on a products attribute set:
http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/creating-custom-layout-handles/

Ideally I want to show certain attributes on the catalog category page for both list and grid view based on the attribute set.

So I have added this in local.xml

```
    <!-- CATALOG LIST / GRID -->
    <PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_Antibodies>
        <reference name="extra.product.detail.list">
            <block type="core/template" name="antibody.detail.extra" template="catalog/product/list/detail/antibodies.phtml" />  
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_Antibodies>
```

And here is the reference to extra.product.detail.list (slimmed down)

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left-flipped.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>            
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">

                <!-- ADDED THIS -->
                <block type="core/text_list" name="extra.product.detail.list" as="extra_product_detail_list" />

            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

I can't seem to get anything to display on the category page? Does that layout update only apply to product pages?

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty workaround .... for now.

```
<?php $attributeSetId = $_product->getAttributeSetId(); ?>
<?php 
$attributeSetDetailTemplate = false;
switch($attributeSetId):
    case 9: // Antibodies
        $attributeSetDetailTemplate = 'antibodies';
    break;
endswitch;
if($attributeSetDetailTemplate) echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/detail/'.$attributeSetDetailTemplate.'.phtml')->setProductId($_product->getId())->toHtml();
                        ?>
```